# GPS coordinate conversion from meters to decimals in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert

I am new to spatial analysis, QGIS & CRSs and seek help with coordinate conversions. I have been told that this is an "easy" process in QGIS but when I tried it, I received the following error:

> Export to vector file failed. Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR
> error: Failed to create file M1.shp: Read-only file system)

I googled this error and I couldn't find anything other than a pdf table containing loads of different QGIS errors.

The steps I followed were:

Import a CVS file (see data below) into QGIS as a text delimited layer with Geometry Definition: Point coordinates and the default Geometry CRS: EPSG:4326-WGS 84

```
Plot ID   X_meters   Y_meters
M1   0.0  364051.75  4109976.75 (plot centre) 
M1   1.1  363997     4109947    (corner) 
M1   1.2  364078     4109926    (corner) 
M1   1.3  364110     4110007    (corner) 
M1   1.4  364022     4110027    (corner)
```

2.Once the points were loaded and visible in QGIS, I used Export features as CRS EPSG:4326-WGS 84 with Geometry type: Automatic (I also tried selecting Point)

How do I do this correctly?

What I am trying to do is convert plot coordinates for some forest plots which were collected in Chile, South America with a regular GPS in a format that I have never seen before: X_meters/Y_meters to match the coordinates of the plots collected with a differential GPS: X_decimals/Y_decimals (first time working with this format also). All my google searches have produced results for converting coordinates from decimals to UTM or other formats and I have not been able to understand the couple of links I've seen for meter to decimal conversions.

I also have the target projection information for the plot coordinates collected with the differential GPS:

```
S_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]]
```

I have looked at the different CRSs in QGIS but none seem to match the above. If it helps, I also have both decimal and meter coordinates for the corners of one of the plots but I have no idea how the conversion was done:

```
Plot ID X_decimal Y_decimal X_meters Y_meters
S1 1.1 -72.09774 -39.604084 749181 5612159
S1 1.2 -72.098203 -39.603312 749144 5612246
S1 1.3 -72.096857 -39.603774 749258 5612191
S1 1.4 -72.097334 -39.60293 749220 5612286
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's **SIRGAS-Chile 2016 / UTM Zone 18S** (`EPSG:9154`).

There are a few projections used in Chile:

- https://epsg.io/?q=Chile%20kind:PROJCRS&page=1

Transforming the WGS84 coordinates to `EPSG:9154` matches the metres in your example. I used a Python script, I wrote a while ago, for testing which you can find below:

```py
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import Point

x = -72.09774
y = -39.604084

wgs84 = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:4326")
utm = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:9154")

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(wgs84, utm, always_xy=True).transform
point = transform(project, Point(x, y))

print(point)
```

The script output is:

```
POINT (749181.0271899529 5612159.049921682)
```

I hope it brings you a step closer to the solution.

---

If you have some Python know-how, you could start with this script:

```py
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import Point

# your coordinates to transform
coordinates = [
    (364051.75, 4109976.75),
    (363997, 4109947),
    (364078, 4109926),
    (364110, 4110007),
    (364022, 4110027),
]

wgs84 = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:4326")
utm = pyproj.CRS("EPSG:9154")

project = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs(utm, wgs84, always_xy=True).transform

for coordinate in coordinates:
    point = transform(project, Point(coordinate[0], coordinate[1]))
    print(point)
```

Result:

```
POINT (-77.03254620311505 -53.14223787917329)
POINT (-77.03337682686404 -53.14249117030619)
POINT (-77.03217553963761 -53.14270049028919)
POINT (-77.03166308520815 -53.14198098282608)
POINT (-77.03296936238479 -53.14177886570875)
```

---

**Or you could use QGIS:** Depending on your data format, you also just can add the data as a layer in QGIS and then right click on the layer, and with `Save as ...` you can save a new file using `EPSG:9154`.